# What is the meaning of '__anonymous' function in a yocto/bitbake recipe?

Tags: python, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

In a yocto project, the core-image.bbclass contains the following code.

```
python __anonymous() {
    ................
    ................
}
```

What is the meaning of the `__anonymous` function here?

Comment: That's not python. Can you provide a link to the file where that code is?

Comment: please find the link for the file below                              https://github.com/openembedded/oe-core/blob/master/meta/classes/core-image.bbclass

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a BitBake recipe, anonymous python code is executed after the recipe is parsed.  You can almost think of it as "post-processing" for a recipe.  That's all there is to it.  Bitbake executes the code within the anonymous block after the recipe is parsed.

Comment: If there is one ore more recipe.bbappend, is __anonymous called after the recipe.bb is parsed, or after all recipe.bb and recipe.bbappend have been parsed?

Comment: after parsing, there will be a single recipe out of all the `.bbappend`, so this anon function will be called once. you can run some experiment with bitbake -p <recipe name>